# What did James V mean by “afferandly”?

Tags: etymology, orthography, meaning, early-modern-english, scottish-english

In [this letter](http://www.ebooksread.com/authors-eng/william-fraser/memorials-of-the-family-of-wemyss-of-wemyss-volume-3-sar/page-3-memorials-of-the-family-of-wemyss-of-wemyss-volume-3-sar.shtml)  from 1536, [King James V of Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_V_of_Scotland) wrote in 1536:

> Veilbelouit frend, we grete yow. Forsamekill as we ar of pourpas
>    to pas to Kelso, and to vesy owr Bordouris for ordoneng of the samyn
>    and for dunputting of sic thyngis as owr pour legis ar hurt hy : Heir-
>    for, we prey yow ry'cht afiectuusly that ye addres yow to be at ws in
>    Sterling with yowr honest howshald, rady and bodin in hors and geir,
>    to remane xx days, **afferandly** to yowr honor and ouris, the penult
>    day of Meii, to pas with ws, as ye will do ws singular plesowr. Gewin
>    at Sterling, the xxi day of Meii, and of owr regne xxiij yeir.

The King’s atrocious spelling notwithstanding :), what does the word ***afferandly*** mean above?

Is this just “some strange Scottish spelling” for something to do with “offering” something?

Has James’s *afferandly* been replaced with another word in contemporary English, or could *afferandly* still be used?

Would it be understood on both sides of Hadrian’s Wall, or only northwards?

Comment: Atrocious spelling? "I am king of the Romans and may override grammar": Emperor Sigismund.

Comment: At least frend, grete, and a few other words here are not misspellings.

Comment: @Kris Oh noes! You and TimLymington both appear to have been the unwitting victims of an incisive sneak-attack by [a saber-toothed tiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED gives it as ‘appropriately, suitably’. Ultimately from *afeir*, and then from ‘Anglo-Norman and Middle French *aferir, afferir*, to appertain, to be appropriate, to be fitting.'

Answer (score 2):

The Dictionary of the Older Scottish Tongue (DOST) defines ***afferandly***/ ***afferandlie***:

> DSL - DOST   **[Afferandly](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/snda4frames.php?xref=yes&searchtype=full&dregion=form&dtext=all&sset=1&fset=20&query=Afferandly), *adv.***  [f. prec. Cf. Efferandly.] **Appropriately, suitably**. —  Bodin in hors and geir … afferandly to yowr honor and owris; **1536** *Wemyss Corr*. 4.  To find sufficient cautioun … afferandlie as is afoirwrittin; **1576** *Edinb. Test.* IV. 221.

Note that the entry cites the same passage as in the question.

[Thanks to @BarryEngland for the OED entry that was the 'seed' for my search.]